# Cygwin not recognizing command

Tags: compilation, makefile, cygwin

I downloaded a "directory".tar.gz, extracted and unzipped the file to obtain "directory".

The installation files for this directory, were to run the make command in cygwin, to compile and pull out the files of the directory, which were written in C.

I attempt to run a command in cygwin, pfunc, which is a command supposed to be available after compiling and performing make, but cygwin says command not found.

I'm completely new to unix and cygwin.

Comment: So my questions comes down to installing and implementing downloaded packages in cygwin on windows

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that pfunc, if it exists, is not on your path.

The first step is to see if pfunc actually exists and if so, find out where.  `find / -xdev -name pfunc` will give you the location of all files named pfunc.  Obviously, if pfunc doesn't exist, you have another problem on your hands.

Next, you'll want to add this path to your bashrc.  You can do that with:

`echo "export PATH=$PATH:<the/path/find/gave/you> >> ~/.bashrc`

Finally, you need to update your path in the current shell with `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I went ahead and ran that command, and this is what popped out, $ find / -name pfunc
find: File system loop detected; `/cygdrive/c/cygwin' is part of the same file system loop as `/'.

Comment: Try `find / -xdev -name pfunc`  as described [here](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2006-01/msg00905.html).  The xdev option will suppress that error.

Comment: thanks so much, when I run the above,  I get...  <br />  user-PC ~  <br />  
$ find / -xdev -name pfunc   <br />  

user-PC ~   <br />  
$  <br />  
...which means not found?

Comment: That is correct.  When you use make in the directory, is it successful? Is the pfunc you referenced [this library?](https://projects.coin-or.org/PFunc)

Comment: I'll try to go through the process later today after work and see if I can make it work.  I'll post the results when I do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22786/discussion-between-usmcs-and-tsribioguy)

Answer (score 0):

K, I figured it out, there was a problem with the implementation of the program on cygwin, and for some reason find -name ....etc couldn't find the file. However, I found the location and reset the path to find the .exe file. Now everything looks good! thanks again!